# Is there way to get the badge and accordion on the same line in lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there way to get the badge and accordion on the same line in lwc?
Tried the span and css changes as well but no change.

[image]

Below is the code:

```
<template>
    <lightning-accordion class="example-accordion">
        <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Accordion Title A">
            <lightning-badge  class="slds-m-left_small" label="ACTIVE"></lightning-badge>
            <lightning-badge  class="slds-m-left_small" label="12"></lightning-badge>
            <p>This is the content area for section A.</p>
      </lightning-accordion-section>

        <lightning-accordion-section name="B" label="Accordion Title B">
            <p>This is the content area for section B.</p>
       </lightning-accordion-section>

        <lightning-accordion-section name="C" label="Accordion Title C">
            <p>This is the content area for section C.</p>
         </lightning-accordion-section>
    </lightning-accordion>
</template>
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

When using a lightning base component, you'll only have as much flexibility as the component is built to allow.

Reviewing the documentation, it appears the label is only a String property, and there isnt a named slot you can use to render a component in place of the Text/String for the Label.

However, there is a slot for the right-hand side of the title/label bar. It is called actions and is intended for buttons or a button menu, but in reviewing the source for the base component in the LWC base components GitHub repo, it doesn't appear to reatrict the kind of component you put in that slot. Worth trying!

If that doesn't work or isn't satisfactory, you could always fork the accordion-* components from the base component repo and build one that meets your needs.